# Is there a way to create an ordered list of items with month as the counter in on HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have to display a list of charities with each one designated to a month. This list is ordered since the charity associated with January should come before the charity associated with February and so on.

By default the ordered list just shows up with 1-12 as the counters for this list and then I have to add the month name as part of the content for each list item. I could also put it as an unordered list, and then the bullet points are more pleasing aesthetically, but this doesn't seem to make sense logically.

Is there a way I can make a list where the month is the counter rather than 1-12?
**January** Charity 1
**February** Charity 2
...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Use psuedo-elements and `list-style-type: none;` to do this.

Html:

```
<ul>
<li class="january">Charity 1</li>
<li class="february">Charity 2</li>
</ul>
```

Css:

```
ul {
list-style-type: none; 
}

li.january:before {
    font-weight: bold;
    content: "January ";
}

li.february:before {
    font-weight: bold;
    content: "February ";
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5e8jt/1/